# Android status bar background disappears when going fullscreen

Tags: android, statusbar

In my android app I have the status bar overlaying on top of the application content. Whenever I go into fullscreen the status bar instantly changes from its current color to translucent and then the status bar icons animate off the screen. I would like to prevent the status bar from going translucent and instead just keep the same color and animate off screen with the icons.

Here's the code I'm using to go fullscreen:

```
int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
```

This issue only seems to happen on lollipop themes.  If I switch from the Material theme to a Holo theme, the status bar animates properly.

Anyone else experience this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to have a translucent status bar when I go into fullscreen by setting flag_translucent_status.  The documentation says it should not be set if you have FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS when trying to set the status bar color.  Not a perfect solution and setting this flag also sets SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE and SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS